# Eclipse WTP - "No tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType" ...?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-wtp

When I double-click on my tomcat server on eclipse's "Servers" tab I get taken to the propeties page. This page has only one tab, "Overview" and has a red square as its icon. When I click on the "Open launch configuration" link on the "Overview" tab I get two popup messages:

> Exception occurred creating launch configuration tabs
>   Reason:
>   No tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType

And:

> No tabs defined for launch configuration type Apache Tomcat

Eclipse's "Error Log" tab has:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_17
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\devsrc

Error
Mon Jan 18 13:38:01 GMT 2010
Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationManager.filterLaunchDelegates(LaunchConfigurationManager.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.hasMultipleDelegates(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.hasDuplicateDelegates(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.getErrorMesssage(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:1163)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.updateMessage(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.refreshStatus(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1159)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.refreshStatus(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:989)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer$8.run(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.initializeContent(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.createContents(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.create(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog(DebugUITools.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationPropertiesDialog(DebugUITools.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.OverviewEditorPart$9.linkActivated(OverviewEditorPart.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$2(AbstractHyperlink.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

What can I do to get it to work?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an installation issue.

Try a new installation of WTP on a clean eclipse (that you can unzip anywhere you want, in order to not mess with your current eclipse installation).

As mentioned in the [WTP download page](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/), you can try their [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) with the p2 update process.

> If you are just getting started with Eclipse or Eclipse Web Tools, you may want to first install from the [Galileo update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/Galileo/), as it would have everything you need to get started.
>
> This Web Tools Platform update site does assume you have all the pre-reqs installed.